# "I'd go careful OR carefully with that"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I have recently used this expression in an answer on another site:

> This is not a frequent structure and I should have more knowledge in the field to discern if you can say that about algorithms.  You can be original and use it, but ***I'd go careful with that*** nonetheless.

While proofreading my answer, it struck me as a rather strange expression. It doesn't look grammatical and I am aware that it is colloquial. When I look it up online, some dictionaries correct it to "go carefully" (which would be grammatically more acceptable) or just define "careful" instead ([Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&biw=1715&bih=827&sxsrf=ALeKk02kg1GkLRim4eeR2bQ5uIeA8nE-uQ%3A1612553769717&ei=KZ4dYLO0K6vV1fAPxeiB4AM&q=go%20careful%20meaning&oq=go%20careful%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgUIABCGAzoHCAAQRxCwA1DYXVjeYWCAbmgBcAJ4AIABrwGIAe8CkgEDMi4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjz7P_0vtPuAhWrahUIHUV0ADwQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)).

However, I am sure I picked it up from native speakers, it just sounds so natural to me. My question is, in this context, are these two sentences perfect synonyms?

> I'd go careful with that.

and

> I'd go carefully with that.

Do they both mean, "I'd be careful with that?"

Comment: I think the issue is the same as “go slow” vs “go slowly” -  *Slow and slowly are usually interchangeable when they come after the verb. However, when the adverb comes before the verb, it only sounds natural to use slowly.* https://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/Slow-Slowly-and-Flat-Adverbs

Comment: @user66974: I can understand your point. However, I sense that "I'd go careful with that" has a more idiomatic meaning than "I'd go slow with that". I am trying to understand its use better.

Comment: Checking  Google Books usage examples, it doesn’t appear there is much difference between the two in meaning -   “Go careful with”  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20careful%20with%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en - “Go carefully with” https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20carefully%20with%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2011,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Comment: In the UK 'go careful' is common in Bristol and West Country regional dialect, and probably others, but is definitely not  standard. They also say 'go steady', which is equally non-standard. Avoid these usages in formal writing.

Comment: @user66974: I didn't expect Google Books to even find instances of  "I'd go careful with that"!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I am well aware it is too colloquial for formal writing. I just want to feel the idiomatic pulse of the language, that's all. I actually spent one year in Somerset a few years ago. Maybe I picked it up there.

Comment: I think yours is just an instance of a wider trend of using adjectives as adverbs, which is not limited  to places or regions.

Comment: “Do not go gentle . . . “

Comment: And then there’s “go easy on,” which, if it fails to succumb to analysis, can simply be called an idiom.

Comment: @Xanne: My intuition was that "I'd go careful with that" rather than just "go careful" tends to become an idiomatic colloquialism. But given the phrases you provided, I understand that this is probably not the case.